What is the difference between .dyn and .dmat in Quantum ESPRESSO?
I'd like to ask to everyone a very basic question regarding Quantum ESPRESSO.
What's the difference between .dmat and .dyn files?
I know I have been bothering you with very trivial questions, but I guarantee I strongly appreciate your help!
Thank you in advance,
Have a good day!

Ok, just realized that .dyn files contain dynamical matrices from phonon calculations while
.dmat files store density matrices from electronic structure calculations
but still, why do I obtain dmat also from ph.x code?

ok, definitely I had no idea of what was I doing!
